# How to know if there is message ready to consume

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka and looking for a way to know if the message is ready for consumption to the consumer before calling consume method.

I am doing the POC on integrating C# with Kafka, previously I did that for RabbitMQ which has a method "MessageCount", but for Kafka, I cannot find any.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ready"? If there's a message in the broker, the consumer will poll it. You don't need to check if the topic is empty or not

Answer (score 0):

Actually Kafka has an infinite loop, in which it calls the poll() function to get eventual new records from a partition.

The configuration : max.poll.intervall.ms, specifies the interval of time after which, if the poll() function is not called, the consumer is considered dead and a rebalance is operated.

So to answer your question, Kafka always calls the poll() function to check if a message is available to be consummed. However, there some consumer configurations that allow to wait for a minimum size of messages before consumming the message:

- **fetch.min.bytes** : you will wait untill you have x bytes of messages to consume them
- **fetch.max.wait.ms** : set how much time you are gonna wait for the fetch.min.bytes to be gathered

Answer (score 0):

In theory, if you can view if messages exist you are already using processes to connect to kafka. So you might as well just do a try catch with consume with the same performance.